# Stuck in infinite loop of unmet dependencies due to broken packages

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, ros, apt-get

This question may appear duplicate of others however, I have tried their solutions but couldn't get any success. I recently removed ROS Indigo using the following command-

```
ravi@lab:~$ sudo apt-get remove ros-*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 12 not upgraded.
```

Now, I needed it. So I tried installing it again using the following command-

```
ravi@lab:~$ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-desktop-full
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-indigo-desktop-full : Depends: ros-indigo-perception but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages
```

.
Unfortunately, the above didn't work. So I tried installing dependencies but got no success-

```
ravi@lab:~$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 12 not upgraded.
ravi@lab:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
ravi@lab:~$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 12 not upgraded.
```

I tried installing the dependency `ros-indigo-perception` manually but no chance-

```
ravi@lab:~$ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-perception
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-indigo-perception : Depends: ros-indigo-perception-pcl but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried more and thought of installing another dependency `ros-indigo-perception-pcl` but got in vain-

```
ravi@lab:~$ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-perception-pcl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-indigo-perception-pcl : Depends: ros-indigo-pcl-conversions but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: ros-indigo-pcl-ros but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Still trying without any success -

```
ravi@lab:~$ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-pcl-conversions
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-indigo-pcl-conversions : Depends: libpcl-1.7-all but it is not going to be installed
                              Depends: libpcl-1.7-all-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

ravi@lab:~$ sudo apt-get install libpcl-1.7-all
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpcl-1.7-all : Depends: libpcl-1.7-all-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

ravi@lab:~$ sudo apt-get install libpcl-1.7-all-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpcl-1.7-all-dev : Depends: libpcl-apps-1.7-dev but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libpcl-io-1.7-dev but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libpcl-outofcore-1.7-dev but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libpcl-people-1.7-dev but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libpcl-recognition-1.7-dev but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libpcl-visualization-1.7-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

**My objective is to install ROS Indigo on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS PC** (without formatting it :D )

Any workaround, please?

Comment: Any suggestions, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it finally. I had to dig more into it and I finally realized that the problem is occurring due to `libusb`.

In order to fix this issue, I first removed `libusb` (sorry, I didn't remember exact version at present). After that, I run `apt-get autoclean`. Then `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` just to make sure everything is at the correct place.

Finally, I used `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-desktop-full` and it worked.

### Note

After restarting PC, the login doesn't work and it says `Failed to start sesssion`. Don't panic, during the login screen press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. It will take you to the terminal. Use your username and password to login. Finally restore the desktop using following command `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`